# Apache2 won't run a Script, PHP-CLI do

Tags: php, apache

I've wrote a script which reads a log-file and write it into an Database. Because of many different line-types it would take about 30 minits executiontime.
Log-Files got:
~20 MB filesize
 
~200.000 lines

If I include it to my website, the script would run only with small log-files(~2MB tested), it won't run till end if i'm using normal-log-files. I included the script like this:

```
<?php
  include "logLauncher/main.php";
?>
```

The strange thing is if i using a syscall it would run.

```
<?php 
  system("php5 logLauncher/main.php");
?>
```

Three last entrys in file: /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:22.210994 2015] [:error] [pid 18893] [client 192.168.0.100:54746] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php:0, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?top=2&left=1&right=1&event=5&trigger=18200&focus=2&filter1=&encounter=11982&&start=2015-05-27%2019:59:07&end=2015-05-27%2020:00:48
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:22.211004 2015] [:error] [pid 18893] [client 192.168.0.100:54746] PHP   2. include() /var/www/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php:121, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?top=2&left=1&right=1&event=5&trigger=18200&focus=2&filter1=&encounter=11982&&start=2015-05-27%2019:59:07&end=2015-05-27%2020:00:48
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:22.211014 2015] [:error] [pid 18893] [client 192.168.0.100:54746] PHP   3. include() /var/www/cowrean_logs/alpha/mod_focus.php:192, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?top=2&left=1&right=1&event=5&trigger=18200&focus=2&filter1=&encounter=11982&&start=2015-05-27%2019:59:07&end=2015-05-27%2020:00:48
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:28.131411 2015] [:error] [pid 18894] [client 192.168.0.100:54747] PHP Notice:  A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /var/www/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php on line 47, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?top=2&left=1&right=1&event=5&trigger=18200&focus=2&filter1=&encounter=11982&start=2015-05-27%2019:59:07&end=2015-05-27%2020:00:48
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:28.131462 2015] [:error] [pid 18894] [client 192.168.0.100:54747] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?top=2&left=1&right=1&event=5&trigger=18200&focus=2&filter1=&encounter=11982&start=2015-05-27%2019:59:07&end=2015-05-27%2020:00:48
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:28.131481 2015] [:error] [pid 18894] [client 192.168.0.100:54747] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php:0, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?top=2&left=1&right=1&event=5&trigger=18200&focus=2&filter1=&encounter=11982&start=2015-05-27%2019:59:07&end=2015-05-27%2020:00:48
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:28.131494 2015] [:error] [pid 18894] [client 192.168.0.100:54747] PHP   2. session_start() /var/www/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php:47, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?top=2&left=1&right=1&event=5&trigger=18200&focus=2&filter1=&encounter=11982&start=2015-05-27%2019:59:07&end=2015-05-27%2020:00:48
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:29.080694 2015] [:error] [pid 18894] [client 192.168.0.100:54747] PHP Notice:  A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /var/www/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php on line 47, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?top=1&left=4&right=0
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:29.080728 2015] [:error] [pid 18894] [client 192.168.0.100:54747] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?top=1&left=4&right=0
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:29.080741 2015] [:error] [pid 18894] [client 192.168.0.100:54747] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php:0, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?top=1&left=4&right=0
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:29.080751 2015] [:error] [pid 18894] [client 192.168.0.100:54747] PHP   2. session_start() /var/www/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php:47, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?top=1&left=4&right=0
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:29.081747 2015] [:error] [pid 18894] [client 192.168.0.100:54747] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: mysqli::$close in /var/www/cowrean_logs/alpha/mod_execute_log.php on line 131, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?top=1&left=4&right=0
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:29.081769 2015] [:error] [pid 18894] [client 192.168.0.100:54747] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?top=1&left=4&right=0
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:29.081790 2015] [:error] [pid 18894] [client 192.168.0.100:54747] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php:0, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?top=1&left=4&right=0
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:29.081801 2015] [:error] [pid 18894] [client 192.168.0.100:54747] PHP   2. include() /var/www/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php:118, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?top=1&left=4&right=0
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:35.819211 2015] [:error] [pid 21277] [client 192.168.0.100:54748] PHP Notice:  A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /var/www/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php on line 47, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?left=7&top=1&right=0    
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:35.819247 2015] [:error] [pid 21277] [client 192.168.0.100:54748] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?left=7&top=1&right=0
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:35.819267 2015] [:error] [pid 21277] [client 192.168.0.100:54748] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php:0, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?left=7&top=1&right=0
[Wed Aug 26 11:11:35.819279 2015] [:error] [pid 21277] [client 192.168.0.100:54748] PHP   2. session_start() /var/www/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php:47, referer: http://192.168.0.10/cowrean_logs/alpha/main.php?left=7&top=1&right=0
```

I would not post whole config-files because "/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini" and "/etc/php5/cli/php.ini" got more than 600 lines!

I think these lines could be interested, but they are in both files identical -.-

```
post_max_size = 20M
max_execution_time = 30
memory_limit = -1
```

Got anyone have a solution for me to kick out the syscall from my code? And include the log-reader script directly into my page? Syscalls doesn't look fine!

Ubuntu 14.4 
PHP5
Apache2
PHP-CLI

Comment: would be interesting to get 2 or 3 more line above (!) "stack trace"

Comment: as u wish, i've added some limes

Comment: You do have the apache-modphp installed, do you?

Comment: only got this
root@ubuntu:/# dpkg -l |grep apache2
ii  apache2 
ii  apache2-bin 
ii  apache2-data
ii  apache2-mpm-prefork 
ii  libapache2-mod-php5
ii  libapache2-mod-svn 
ii  libapache2-mod-wsgi 
ii  libapache2-svn

Comment: but i think you're talking about<br> libapache2-mod-php5 - server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)

Comment: i haven't installed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the script in question add this at the top of the code

```
<?php

    ini_set('max_execution_time', -1 );
```

This will tell PHP not to timeout this script.

It has its dangers, for example if you manage to code and infinite loop then the script will run till you kill either apache or PHP, depending on your configuration.

It is best not to change this in the php.ini as that will effect every php script.

Comment: This seems like it's working thanks i will test some other values e.g. 40 mins

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time  --> "The maximum execution time is not affected by system calls, stream operations etc. Please see the set_time_limit() function for more details."

Comment: that sentence might be the different!